# Cannot access wcf service hosted on iis from php with soapclient

Tags: c#, php, wcf, iis

This has been really painful for the last few hours and I just have no more ideas what to do.

Tried many solutions that I found on here without any luck...

I have an iis server that is hosting a wcf web service. Simple stuff.

I can connect to this (example: http://mydomain.com/Service.svc?wsdl) from the iis server and all other computers without any problems.

So I went on to make a php client on my computer - (using xampp via localhost) - (not on the iis server)

```
        $wcfClient = new SoapClient('http://mydomain.com/Service.svc?wsdl');
    $args = //input data
    $response = $wcfClient->GetData($args);
    print_r($response->GetDataResult->Post);
```

This works perfect. No problems at all. It returns all the data... Then I went on to upload this to my hosting account. This is the error I keep getting.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ....
```

I have no more ideas. Disabled firewall, changed web.config a million times and still no luck. I tried the file_get_contents method to see what's up. I keep getting:

```
failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

Comment: can you access the wsdl url from the browser without credentials? do you have proxy to connect internet?

Comment: @Damith yes I can. From every machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this by changing the port to 80 on the iis server...